# Writing in a 2gb txt file

Tags: text-editors

So I have a 2 gb .txt file and I want to add a character before every existing line.
How can I do it from linux or windows?
I opened it with programs like glogg but it's read only :(

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is native on Linux and available on Windows. Assuming the character is `x`, a Linux command line would be.

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)/x\1/' /path/to/file
```

Will write the changed file to stdout. Use `sed -i` to apply the changes directly to the file.

**CAVEAT**

Some file systems (like FAT) will not allow files to grow beyond 2GB - in this case you are hitting the limit of a file system, not of the text processing.

Comment: FAT16 is ancient, it's unlikely that it will be a culprit here.

Comment: FAT32 has the same limitation (to be precise: the theoretical limit is 4GB, but the implementation limit oten is 2GB), and it is widely used e.g. in SDHC cards. Something about a 2GB text file lets me think of some data logger, which might use such a thing.

Comment: If linux is used, its often not FAT though....